# When i try to run a spark code on a parquet file, the query execution plan fails with error

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

When i try to run a spark code on a parquet file, the query execution plan fails with error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encountered error while reading file file:///C:/Users/Downloads/abc.parquet. Details:
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFilesError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:731)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:283)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:561)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] Caused by: java.io.IOException: can not read class **org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader: Socket is closed by peer.**
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.read(Util.java:365)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.format.Util.readPageHeader(Util.java:132)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readPageHeader(ParquetFileReader.java:1382)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1429)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$Chunk.readAllPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1402)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readChunkPages(ParquetFileReader.java:1023)
[error]         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextFilteredRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:1008)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase$ParquetRowGroupReaderImpl.readNextRowGroup(SpecificParquetRecordReader
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:388)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:309)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:212)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:274)
[error]         ... 20 more
```

I am using latest spark version 3.3.0 and the parquet files are generated by go service

I tried processing the file using a filter query on certain fields it shows issues

for eg:

```scala
val test1 = volumedata_par_latest.filter(
    col("isClone")==="true" &&
    col("id") =!= "" &&
    col("customerId") =!= "" &&
    col("systemId") =!= "" &&
    col("parent_vol_id") =!= "" &&
    col("parent_vol_id").isNotNull &&
    col("collectionId") =!= ""
)
```

In this particular statement when the isClone condition is removed the execution works , but if it is present it fails.In some other parquet if condition for parent_vol_id presence creates the same issue. When we see the parquet data it looks correct to me

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having the exact same error, depending on the filter it raises an error or not